# How to do a format with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular-moment

why momemnt shows 12 hr as below code.

```
let x =moment("2018-12-11 00:00").format("hh:mm:ss");
console.log(x);
```

expected output: 00:00:00,
Recieved : 12:00:00

stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-85eraf?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Use .format("HH:mm:ss"); to get 24 hour representation

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the lowercase `hh` to uppercase: `HH` in `.format("hh:mm:ss");`

`hh` is the 12-hour, while `HH` is the 24-hour format.

You can get more details in their [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 1):

try `.utc` method and change hh to HH:

```
let x =moment.utc("2018-12-11 00:00").format("HH:mm:ss");
```